# Detect jsch disconnection

Tags: detection, disconnect, jsch

How can I detect from the client that jsch session has been disconnected by the server?

Answer (score 1):

You mean other than the isConnected() function on the session object?

Comment: Yes, since it returns true even if i disconnect from the internet while tunneling a remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

If you setup a portforwarding with setPortForwardingL() you can use a function like this to verfiy if the tunnel (and the connection) is still alive. (The example tunnels the Echo Service).

```
public boolean performCheck() throws Exception {
    Socket socket;

    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 7);

        if (socket.isConnected()) {
            socket.close();
            return true;
        }
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // nothing special
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // nothing special
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: It seems that the status of a connection in JSch is only updated if some action occurs over this connection. Therefore the described way seems the only one to be sure if the connection is still up.

Answer (score 1):

```
Session.isConnected()
```

works for me but must be sure you call

```
Session.setServerAliveInterval(int)
```

before

```
Session.connect()
```